# How to map schema dynamically in Copy Activity when source and destination both are dynamic?

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-files

I am working with a scenario where I have one azure file storage account in which I have different folders, each contains the *.csv file. I want to load each *.csv file in different Azure SQL Database tables dynamically by iterating over the my RootFolder.

The problem I am facing is my *.csv file contains more columns than my destination. When copy activity gets triggered following error is encountered:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make your dataset schema as [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions). And then use [GetMetadataActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to get schema of each file.